# Python formatting in VSCode ruins Django templates

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

I am writing a Django app and I use the following configuration in VSCode (`settings.json`) to auto-format my Python code (I use the Django VSCode extension as well):

```json
{
    "liveshare.authenticationProvider": "GitHub",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "html.format.endWithNewline": true,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/__pycache__": true
    },
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--ignore=E501,E266,W503"
    ],
    "files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
        "*.html": "django-html"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},
}
```

While formatting in Python files works as expected, it seems to interfere with my Django templates as well and ruins them.

For example, the following template...

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load martortags %}

{% block title %}MyBlog - {{ object.title }}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<ol>
{% for post in object_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endblock content %}
```

...becomes this after save:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load martortags %} {% block title %}MyBlog - {{
object.title }}{% endblock title %} {% block content %}
<ol>
  {% for post in object_list %}
  <li><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endblock content %}
```

As seen in `settings.json`, I tried to follow the instructions in the Django VSCode extension docs, but it didn't work. As a matter of fact, nothing changes regardless if the `"files.associations"` and `"emmet.includeLanguages"` settings exist or not in `settings.json`.

How can I decouple `.py` file formatting (correctly identified by VSCode as `Python` files) from `.html` file formatting (correctly identified by VSCode as `Django Template` files) and perhaps use an ordinary HTML formatter for the latter?

Answer (score 2):

The `black` formatter of Python will not format the `.html` file.

I am not sure which format you have selected for the `.html` file. You can have a look at the `User settings.json` try to find this:

```
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": xxx
  }
```

You can right-click the editor and choose `Format Document with` to find out which format caused it. The `Prettier Code formatter` extension looks like can cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension [djLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monosans.djlint). Then, in your settings.json, add:

```json
{
    "[html][django-html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint"
    },
    // ...
}
```

The following is an example how to mix formatters, here djLint, [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), and [Black](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter):

```json
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter"
    },
    "[html][django-html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint"
    },
    // ...
}
```